# How to use variable in xls file as input parameter

Tags: r

I usually declare some variables for next process input, but i want to move all variables into a separate xlsx file but still confused on how to call the variables

```
start_dt <- 20211001
end_dt <- 20211031
```

I'm expecting the variables are split just like above code so i can use each of them separately, but now they are in single vector

```
param_date <- read_excel("D:/Model/parameter.xlsx",sheet="date") %>% 
  as_vector()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, the following should work to extract them:

```
param_date <- read_excel("D:/Model/parameter.xlsx",sheet="date") %>% 
  as_vector()
start_dt <- param_date[3]
end_dt <- param_date[4]
```

Comment: i add more variables, but it cause changes in column position, which i have to modify again to define start_dt and end_dt. is there any way to use the "var" column in xlsx as variable name and "value" as the input?

Answer (score 0):

modified my code, not 100% as i want but at least it can read header name as variable. still looking for a neater option to read directly from dataframe without additional step to declare each variable again.

```
param_date <- read_excel("D:/Model/parameter.xlsx",sheet="date") %>% 
  as.data.frame()

start_dt <- param_date[param_date$var=="start_dt",2]
end_dt <- param_date[param_date$var=="end_dt",2]
start_dt2 <- param_date[param_date$var=="start_dt2",2]
period <- param_date[param_date$var=="period",2]
```